# WordPress Twenty Fifteen - list only post titles in category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress with the Twenty Fifteen theme.

I am trying to list only the article titles in the category page.

The default way lists the entire article, but this is not what I want.
I just need the title.
Ideally it would also sort the posts by title name (ascending).

The default code looks like this:

```
      <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying archive pages
     *
     * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
     * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
     *
     * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
     * new template file for each one. For example, tag.php (Tag archives),
     * category.php (Category archives), author.php (Author archives), etc.
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
     * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
     */

get_header(); ?>
<section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
            ?>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

        // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</section><!-- .content-area -->
```

I have tried editing this part of code and trying things such as:

```
get_template_part( 'title', get_post_format() );
```

and other variations but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

As you're in the Wordpress loop you can use the_title(), like this

```
<?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php
        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

        // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );
```

See this page for more information

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answer!

I have tried this method and it does not work.
It does return all the titles in the category but they are all in just one line and are not clickable.

So I am trying to achieve the functionality of the original command but instead of having the content of the article as well I would just want the title (and have it click-able).

Thank you,

Comment: See updated answer to make the link clickable and on multiple lines.